# Installation of IBM RAD 7.5 fails with JVM crash

Tags: java, jvm, crash

I am trying to install IBM RAD, while installation, I am getting this error -

JVM terminated exit code=8096

And the installation stops. Is there any way to rectify this problem? Why Does JVM terminates? I verified that this is the jre from IBM which is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this problem was to DISABLE the Device3d driver. After disabling the "DirectDraw" and Direct3D accelerations, RAD installed fine.
Way to disable is - Open Display Properties -> Settings -> Advanced->Troubleshoot
And lower the Hardware Acceleration to "Disable all but basic accelerations".

Answer (score 0):

one thing you could try is to delete the shared classes cache because this error **may** be caused by a corrupted cache, the commands to do that are:

```
java -Xshareclasses:listAllCaches // to see the caches you have

java -Xshareclasses:destroy,name=myCacheName // to destroy the cache
```

Or just

```
java -Xshareclasses:destroy // to destroy all caches...
```

more information [here](http://www.webagesolutions.com/knowledgebase/waskb/waskb030/index.html)...